# Python: Apply if statement from string

Tags: python, if-statement

I have an if statement in a .ini file:

```
critical= $TREND$>=40
```

In my script I replace $TREND$ by my value so I have in a variable:

```
critical = "10.5>=40"
```

I try to execute this if statement to know if it's True or False.

```
if critical:
   print "It's critical!"
```

(I know it will just check if critical is empty)

Comment: You could `eval` the string, but that's potentially risky - the `.ini` file could contain anything. Why not parse it?

Comment: i would advice you to have critical_low a critical_high in your .ini which will make your code better. `eval` is evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
critical = eval("10.5>=40")
```

However, you must be sure that what is "eval'ed" is completely trusted, because it allows you to execute any arbitrary python code.  That is, don't use this if any part of the string is passed in by an "untrusted entity" (user, external api, etc).

Another, possibly better, option might be to use a "template parser" which allows "untrusted" or "sandboxed" execution.  For example, the [Jinja Sandbox mode](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/sandbox/).

Comment: Indeed I know this is bad in a security perspective but this is awesome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would urge you to change your `.ini` to have following:

`critical_low`

`critical_high`

this way you avoid two problems - you don't have to use `eval` which can be very dangerous, and you don't have logic in your `.ini` unless you do want logic there which still can be solved without using `eval`

said that `eval` will work fine if it's just a hacky script

Comment: It's just I need the operator. Sometime critical will be $VALUE$<1

Comment: fair enough :) you can always add `critical_operator` but it will bloat your code somehow. guess i just really don't like `eval` :)